# make a password protected bash script resist/refuse "bash -x" when the password is given

Tags: bash, passwords, gnupg

I want to give my long scripts to customer. The customer must not be able to read the scripts even if he has the password. The following command locks and unlocks the script but the  `set +x` is simply ignored.

The code:

```
read -p 'Script: ' S &&
  C=$S.crypt \
  H='eval "$((dd if=$0 bs=1 skip=//|gpg -d) 2>/dev/null)";
    exit;' &&
  gpg -c<$S | cat >$C <(echo $H | sed s://:$(echo "$H" | wc -c):) - \
    <(chmod +x $C)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is the actual problem you're trying to solve?  It seems to me rather unlikely that you can prevent the person running the script from reading the script--not only due to set -x.

Comment: I want to give to customer a script that he can run by entering a password. The customer must not be able to see the code via cat/vim/bash -x. To counter the "bash -x" we can use set +x in the beginning of the script but it does not work for the password protected script. we run bash -x script.secure, put the password and we see the commands even if the script starts with set +x

Comment: Yes I know it doesn't work.  You won't be able to solve this problem this way.  It may be fairly impractical to solve this at all.  Consider whether you really need to do this--it seems unlikely that you do.

Comment: You do realize nothing prevents the user from running the given decryption command manually to read the script, right?

Answer (score 4):

Given that it is an interpreted script that at some point must be loaded into memory and interpreted it is impossible to completely avoid anyone being able to dump out the contents of the script. It can easily be achieved i.e. with a wrapper script around the bash executable...

Comment: If we use c++ for example and at some point we need to call a system command, or call an external program like gnuplot, wget etc then there is no way to hide the syntax that we used to call these programs. Correct?

Comment: You are correct. While there are other means you could do what I mentioned with all of these - create wrapper scripts that writes the arguments to file. At some point 'normal' users will give up, though... ;)