# hide bash code which is inside c plus plus program

Tags: c++, bash, obfuscation

I am embedding bash in cpp. Can the bash code be hidden (when we cat the executable to not be able to see the bash code)
The simple code I am using:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;


#define test1 "\
#!/bin/sh --posix \n\
echo \"2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222\"  \n\
"


int main()
{

system(test1);     
return 0;

}
```

Without any counter measures, when we used system commands, or the "define" method as seen above, after compilation we can cat the executable and read the bash commands.

Comment: You would need to encrypt the bash strings and then decrypt them at run-time.

Comment: This is basically the same problem as in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20468373/1126841): you can't truly encrypt a string if you have to also distribute the key along with it.

Comment: **Why** do you want to do this? If this is for security, hiding code does not fundamentally make it more secure. If you are embedding a password in a bash command, for instance, you really should not be doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be hard to avoid using a define.

However, if you really want it hidden from `cat` or `string`, you can do so.

1. Make the entire thing a const string, but not the string you currently have.  Instead, manually go through each character, and bitwise XOR it with some value (0xA or 0x5 is a good bet).
2. When you want to run the system call, create a copy of the string and un-bitwise XOR it again, then run system on the result.

Of course, anyone reading your code will really raise their eyebrows and wonder what you're doing that needs to be so encrypted, but this will avoid the issue of it being visible to ascii scans.

Note that this is a simple, specific implementation of the general suggestion in the comments by Paul R.

Comment: Don't you mean exclusive or?

Comment: @RichardPennington Yes, I do.  I blame Monday morning for that.  Thanks, fixed.

Comment: This protects from casual cat/strings, but as people point out, it's not in any way secure, and the string is trivially recoverable with strace.

Comment: @thatotherguy Agreed.  What this does, and ALL it does is hide strings from ASCII scans.  This concept also won't find the cure for the common cold, but I never claimed it would.  :-P

Comment: @ScottMermelstein I didn't mean to imply you did. I added it as a footnote to your answer.